# fixed-width font (usually Courier) in htm

Tags: pre, p-lang

i'm, new on learning html (for front-end)
i encountered with a subject that includes fixed-width font (usually Courier) in some web pages like w3schools.So after seraching alot,
i couldn't find a good answer for that.Can anyone explain it with an example?

Comment: Do you mean fixed-width (= mono spaced = non-proportional) font: every symbol having the same width.`m` being a bit compressed, and `i` having empty room at bot sides? It is (still) used for code; also for numerical text in columns, for console (command line). In HTML the `<pre>....</pre>` (preformatted) text generally is fixed width. HTML style: `<span style='font-family: monospace, Consolar, DejaVu Sans Mono, Lucida Console, Courier, "Courier New";'>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span>`

Answer (score 1):

A "fixed width font" is a style of glyphs (a glyph is the human visible representation of a character as displayed on the computer's screen or as printed on paper) such that every character has the same horizontal length.

Fixed width fonts are needed for "ASCII art" displays such as this:

```
I want to highlight this word.  So I use "^" characters on
the next line like this: ^^^^
```

If the width was not fixed, the "^" characters might not be aligned correctly.